# Why is it called coffee cake?

Tags: cake, coffee

There is no coffee in any of the recipes I've seen for coffee cake, so why is it called that?

Comment: Note that some people use "coffee cake" to describe cakes which contain coffee. In my house when I was growing up, "coffee cake" was coffee-flavoured sponge, usually with coffee-flavoured icing.

Comment: If you've not tried coffee cake (with coffee in it), Coffee and walnut cake is incredible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is traditionally served **with coffee** when getting together with friends for coffee; kind of like tea-cakes are served at tea-time.